# Applying Fubini's theorem to find the expected value of a random variable

Tags: improper-integrals, expected-value, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I don't understand how we get this equality:

With $y$ non negative,
$$\int_0^{\infty}\left(\int_y^{\infty}f(x)dx\right) dy$$
$$=\int_0^{\infty}\left(\int_0^{x}dy\right)f(x)dx$$

When I apply Fubini, I get

$$\int_0^{\infty}\left(\int_y^{\infty}f(x)dx\right) dy$$
$$=\int_y^{\infty}\left(\int_0^{\infty}dy\right)f(x)dx$$

$f$ is the probability density function of a continuous random variable $Y$.

Edit: Ok so when the bounds of the double integral aren't constants, we have to consider more carefully the area over which we are integrating. In the initial integral, we are integrating over the area formed by $0 \leq y \leq \infty$ and $y \leq x \leq \infty$, where we integrate by $x$ first (integrating "vertically" on the xy axis). If we wish to integrate by $y$ first (integrating "horizontally" on the xy axis), we must define the area over which we are integrating like this: $0 \leq y \leq x$ and $0 \leq x \leq \infty$. These become the bounds of the new integral.

Comment: You can't have an already integrated variable leftover in your bounds on the outside. It would be good to review exercises in your favorite multivariable calculus book on how to swap bounds properly. In this case the relevant inequality by looking at the first bounds is $$0 < y < x < \infty$$

Comment: All you've done is swap the integral symbols, without regard for the region you're integrating over. In particular, if you integrate with respect to $y$, every $y$ involved should no longer exist in the expression, yet you have one on the outermost integral.